# Quarter-Circle inscribed in a Square.

Tags: geometry, circles

*Quadrilateral ABCD is a square with a side length of 4 cm. A quarter-circle with radius 4 cm and centered at D connects A and C, and a quarter-circle with the same radius centered at B also connects A and C. What is the combined area of both dark regions in the figure at right? Leave your answer in terms of pi.*

Hello! I was in a math competition earlier this year and missed this problem. 
My reasoning:
The area of the dark region = Area of square - Unshaded Area
Let's call the dark region, d and the unshaded area, u.

d = 16 - [2(PI)(4)^2]/4  --- Because the area of a circle is PI * radius^2 and there are 2
                             quarter circles.

d = 16-8*PI

My answer is incorrect, but can someone show me my error? Thank you.

[image: Picture depicted on the Problem Sheet]

Comment: notice that answer is 2[16-pi*16/4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the midst of a competition you can make all sorts of careless mistakes, but you should at least now see your answer cannot be correct, since $16<8\pi$ so your answer is negative, which is obviously undesirable.

When you get a negative area, what happened is that you took away too much; in this case that is true; you took away the white region *twice* while only adding in the square *once*.

The error is relatively easy to fix, fortunately. Your construction also took away the shaded region once (one part for each quarter-circle), so if you add back in the entire square then you have

- added shaded region twice
- subtracted shaded region once
- added unshaded region twice
- subtracted unshaded region twice

which means you have added exactly the shaded region, exactly once; that is the desired area. This does agree with the $32-2\pi(16)/4 = 32-8\pi$ of Sry's comment. (As a sanity check, since $\pi<4$ we have that this answer is at least positive).

Answer (score 1):

**Area of Square:**

$$\text{A}=\text{l}^2=4^2=16$$

**Area of Unshaded Region:**
To find this you'd find the area of the segment but you'd have to multiply this area by $2$ since there is a symmetric unshaded segment adjacent to it with the same area.
$$\text{A}=\frac{r^2}{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{180}c - \sin c\right)$$

Where $r$ is the radius and $c$ is the central angle in degrees. The radius is $4$ since it is equal to the length of a side of the square and $c$ is $90$ degrees since every corner of a square forms right angles. 
$$\text{A}=2\left(\frac{4^2}{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{180}\cdot 90-\sin 90\right)\right)=16\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-1\right)$$

**Area of Shaded Region $=$ Area of Square $-$ Area of Unshaded Region**
$$\text{A}=16-16\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-1\right) = 16-\frac{16\pi}{2}+16 =32-\frac{16\pi}{2}=32-8\pi=8(4-\pi)$$

Answer (score 1):

Draw a diagonal.  Then the shaded area is $2\cdot (\text{quarter of the circle}-\text{quarter of the quadrilateral})$.